# Can I assign the method of an extended record to an event in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2007

Given the following record type:

```
type
  TMyRecord = record
  private
    procedure SomeMethod(_Sender: TObject);
  end;
```

should it be possible to assign this method as the event handler?

```
var
  MyRecord: TMyRecord;
begin
  Button1.OnClick := MyRecord.SomeMethod;
end;
```

In Delphi 2007 I get an internal compiler error C1264 after the assignment.

I am not sure whether the internal structure of a Record's method fulfill the requirements for being assigned to an event pointer.

EDIT:
As David Heffernan pointed out, this is a compiler bug in Delhpi 2007. I ended up using the following workaround:

```
type
  TMyRecord = record
  private
    procedure SomeMethod(_Sender: TObject);
    function GenerateNotifyEvent(_CodePtr: pointer): TNotifyEvent;
  end;

function TMyRecord.GenerateNotifyEvent(_CodePtr: pointer): TNotifyEvent;
var
  Method: TMethod;
begin
  Method.Data := @Self;
  Method.Code := _CodePtr;
  Result := TNotifyEvent(Method);
end;

var
  MyRecord: TMyRecord;
begin
  Button1.OnClick := MyRecord.GenerateNotifyEvent(@TMyRecord.SomeMethod);
end;
```

Not as nice as a simple assignment, but good enough. I just wish I could simply update to a newer version of Delphi where that bug has been fixed.

Comment: What if you write an event property on your record?

Comment: If you can change `TMyRecord` you could make it an `object` as a workaround. I have done that in D2007 for some time and haven't noticed problems.

Comment: @LURD same problem: Internal compiler error

Comment: @UliGerhardt Changing it into an object would solve the issue, but I'd like to avoid that.

Comment: To be clear: I mean `object`, not `class`. So it's only a style issue.

Comment: @UliGerhardt Oh, you meant those TurboPascal style objects. Yes, that would have been another possible solution, but one I'd like even less than the hack I am now using since those objects have been no longer supported officially for nearly two decades.

Comment: AFAICT they mostly work in D2007. And you can IFDEF them to `record`s for later Delphis that don't have that compiler bug.

Comment: @UliGerhardt `object` has had lots of problems too in recent times. You might be swapping one problem for another!

Comment: @David, I know and therefore I'm only using them only in simple cases and very rarely - e.g. when advanced records yield ICEs. :-) But I'll have a look at your TMethod method too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you should be able to do this. You can assign the following type of methods:

- Instance methods of classes.
- Class methods of classes.
- Instance methods of records.
- Instance methods of objects, that is the deprecated types introduced with the `object` keyword.

Since this is an internal compiler error, this would appear to be a compiler bug in Delphi 2007. Certainly your code will compile in later versions of Delphi.

[QC#59807](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=59807) seems to be very similar to your issue. According to that bug report it was resolved in build 11.0.2902.10471. Then again, perhaps it is this one: [QC#60621](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=60621) which is reported as being resolved in build 12.0.0.15784.

If you cannot upgrade to a compiler that does not have the fault, then do this:

```
var
  Method: TMethod;
....
Method.Code := @TMyRecord.SomeMethod;
Method.Data := @MyRecord;
Button1.OnClick := TNotifyEvent(Method);
```

Comment: Is there any other way of assigning such a method? e.g. Could I typecast it to something (like TMethod) to avoid the compiler error?

Comment: It's not a compiler error. It's an internal compiler error. That is an ICE. In other words, a compiler bug.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of the difference. I still would like to circumvent this.

Comment: I've given you a workaround that should do the job. I cannot test it in D2007 mind you. However, I'd be astounded if it did not work in D2007.

Comment: Yes, this workaround avoids the ICE and works. I can even do the assignment inside another method of the record as Method.Data := @Self

Answer (score 2):

It works in XE7.  No warnings.  Method content executes as expected on button click.